# How to set inactive timeout on identity server 4?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using identity server 4 and react-oidc-context.

How i can setup and configure the inactive timeout (logged in user do nothing) for automatically logout the user?

I found some properties like `ExpireTimeSpan/SlidingExpiration` but it automatically logout the user when the user do something.